# How can I set the class of a span based on the value of an object?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code:

```
<span class="msg" data-ng-show="question.message == 'Correct'" style="color: green;">Correct</span>
<span class="msg" data-ng-show="question.message == 'Incorrect'" style="color: red;">Incorrect</span>
<span class="msg" data-ng-show="question.message == 'Answers Shown'">Answers Shown</span>
```

Is there a way that I can set the class to "red" or "green" or nothing so I can combine these three lines into one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be:

```
<style>
 .Correct{
  color: green; 
 }
 .Incorrect{
  color: red; 
 }
</style>

<span class="msg {{question.message}}" >{{question.message}}</span>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/fYFJp/

Comment: It's a working solution but I think a problem if I decide later that I want to have a different color for a different type of message that has more than two words in it like "No Answers".

Comment: @Anne you can use it like: `class="msg {{question.message.replace(' ','')}}" ` : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/fYFJp/1/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)
You can use them any expression like in ng-show to compute class name

Comment: You have great example in angular documentation which I was linked.

Comment: Please I don't think it's normal in stackoverflow to just give a link as an answer to a question. I've seen this before and the answers like this often get downgraded.